How to Remove Deprecated Webform External Optional Library?
The status report for my site displays this warning:

Deprecated modules installed
Deprecated modules found: Webform Algolia Places.

The library is definitely installed (I see the files in the site's libraries directory), but it isn't listed on the admin/structure/webform/config/libraries page. I've tried removing the entries for algolia/places entries from my composer.libraries.json and then running "composer update drupal/webform" in my site's root directory. That produced the following output:
Gathering patches from patch file.
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing algolia/places (1.19.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing algolia/places (1.19.0)
Deleting web/libraries/algolia.places - deleted

After composer update completed, I rebuilt caches by running "drush cr". The library files are no longer present in my site's libraries directory. However, the status report warning is still there. Did I miss a step? is there something else I need to do to remove the library?

That's a module, rather than (or maybe "as well as") a library.
To remove the warning, uninstall the webform_location_places module.
